# SubCollection under document in collection

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using flutter to create collection > userid> collection>doc>subscollection.

So user will create a item and this item will have properties. So i want to create a subcollection for these properties.

So that i can pull all the properties associated with that item.

So item collection will have few details and then properties subcollection will have other details.

Item is created in one page where when user clicks on create, i take them to properties page.

So when they click on elevate button, i am using following code to send the doc id to properties page

```
  var docId =FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('items')
          .doc(userud).collection('items').doc().id;


                Navigator.of(context)
                    .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
               properties(data: docId)));
```

Now in properties page, i am trying to receive the doc id with following;

```
         class properties extends StatefulWidget {
        final data;
       properties({Key? key, required this.data}) : super(key: key);
       String user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

      @override
      State<properties> createState() => _properties();
      }
```

Then i am loading it using following;

```
     late final documentID;
  void initState() {
super.initState();

documentID=widget.data;

 }
```

Then finally to add document in properties following code in elevate button

```
CollectionReference coll = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('items').
doc(user).collection('items').doc(data)
.collection('properties');
```

Instead of creating properties under items's doc, it is creating a separate collection parallel to items.

Please help.

Comment: I have posted an answer below. Please check and let me know if you need any additional help with my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your case with Firestore web version 9 client library and I am able to create a ‘properties’ collection under ‘cities’ collection’s doc, it is not creating a separate collection parallel to ‘cities’.

This is what I implemented :

`“collection-> doc-> collection-> doc->sub collection”`, for my case it is `cities-> 101(doc id)-> cities->id(doc id)->properties->(doc id)`:

[image]

Below is the working code in JS,

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import {doc, setDoc, getFirestore,collection} from "firebase/firestore"

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional

const firebaseConfig = { 

      //your firebaseConfig
   };

const app=initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db=getFirestore(app);
const cityRef = doc(collection(db, 'cities/101/cities'));
const id=cityRef.id;
const colRef=collection(db,`cities/101/cities/${id}/properties`)
const docRef=doc(colRef);
setDoc(docRef,{"name":"hawai"})
console.log(id);
// setDoc(cityRef, { capital: true }, { merge: true });
```